# USB Drive not usable after Windows 10 update

Tags: hard-drive, usb, windows-10

After an automatic update in (not to) Windows 10 my external USB drive is no longer visible in explorer. It is visible in Disk Manager but I can't assign it a drive letter (it says that it can't find the file).

I can't access the computer or drive physically so everything is done using TeamViewer. What I've tried:

- I've disabled and re-enabled the USB devices in the device manager
- I've set the drive offline and then online in disk manager

What more can I try? The drive is a Seagate Backup Plus Desktop 3TB.

Answer (score 2):

Too bad you can't just try unplugging it and then plugging it back into a different usb port. If you can't physically do that yourself, perhaps you could ask someone who can to do that for you. Maybe a restart is in order?

What file system and partitioning scheme is / was on it? Is / are the partition(s) still logically intact?

Short of that, if this system is not a VM itself, I would try loading up a VM on it, preferably (obviously) one that supports physical communication with usb hardware. Maybe fire up an easy to use linux distro, such as fedora, in virtualbox (I think that supports options for VM access to usb hardware these days). From there, you can then try to access the drive, gather more information, and also run a plethora of additional diagnostic tools on it.

Addendum in response to your update: Your question pre-supposes that there is something about the drive (or its partition(s), and/or the filesystem contained therein and the contents thereof) that is in *need* of repair. If you can indeed access the files on the drive from within your linux VM on this host system, that suggests to me that the drive and its contents are probably not the issue here. It could be a device driver bug within windows, or some weird interaction between the drive's firmware and the windows usb subsystem; up against a proprietary brick wall either way.

Having said that, most linux distros, including ubuntu, provide a "Disks" gui utility (very similar ui as to what you'd find on a macosx system), and various other utilities (mostly command-line based) which are too numerous to mention here.

What you can do instead: Some virtualization management software allows you to share files directly between the host and its VMs, or provide some form of access to the VM's filesystems from within the host environment. If that's not an option, a workaround at that point would be to share out the drive's contents via samba from within the VM, and then map a drive connection to that network share/unc path from within the host environment. Or you could enable ssh inside the VM, and then transfer files via an sftp client (such as [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or [winscp](https://winscp.net)) on the host side. Sounds a little ridiculous, I know, but based on what you're saying, you may not have any other options. Bottom line: if both the VM and its host can see each other on the network, then with the proper configuration, they can share files via said network communications. Sorry so verbose, but I wanted to be thoroughly clear.

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu and can there access the files on the drive. Is there some tool that I can try to repair the drive (without loosing any files)?